# QGIS/PostGIS Difference Geoprocessing with tolerance

Tags: qgis, postgis, erase, link, eliminate

This is probably an extended question from my another question ([Increase spatial query performance (st_difference)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291079/increase-spatial-query-performance-st-difference))

This is the background is this. I have a road link and a tunnel link.
From the road link, I need to erase the tunnel link out.
With builtin GIS geoprocessing, I can use these tools Erase tool in ArcMap, Difference toon in QGIS.

I used ArcMap erase tool, and it seemed to work fine.
with QGIS tool, some areas were fine but another areas did not work well.

I assume that major issue was the topology of two links were not the same. (It does look like but it was not).

I wonder why ArcGIS returned the answer that I want but QGIS/PostGIS didn't.
Also, I would like to have exact same answer of ArcGIS erase tool in QGIS (though I know it is difference but I wonder if there are any tricks...)

Here is one of the screenshots of ugly areas.
considering that the scale is negative 9832 (1: -9832) the topology error? is not viewable with ArcMap (I suppose)
[image]

Comment: it is possible that ArcGIS uses a looser tolerance for geometrical equality per default than QGIS, e.g. it implicitly snaps vertices while erasing. with that answer I gave you in your other question, it's easy to expand the tunnel geometries with a tiny buffer to make sure those nasty lines will intersect. there are also other ways, like `ST_Snap` or, possibly easier, `ST_SnapToGrid`. screwed up topologies can be a huge pain, though...

Comment: regardless of the software, zooming more than 1:1 will produce some visual misalignments that are not necessarily true